# Device Strategy for mobile application testing

Tags: mobile

I am looking for device strategy , how should approach . I mean we are using real devices for testing. I need to present to my customer for if I should continue using real devices or use cloud based mobiles 
1. I have team at one location only 
2. I can use open source tools like appium for automation
I am not able to come to conclusion as there is security issue too with cloud based like perfecto. I know that they have private offerings but still customer is not convinced on security part. Please suggest any approach
For why should I use cloud and how much should I use it

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://qtp.blogspot.com/2015/02/mobile-application-testing.html) post might answer you question. It answers different questions on Mobile Application Testing.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.